# How can I change the location of files in xcode project?

Tags: xcode

I put some files on the same level of `*.xcodeproj` file carelessly. When I move these files into the right location in Finder， Xcode  tells me that these files are missing. So I delete the group which contains these files whose names have been read (I realize it is a mistake). And I drag these files from Finder into the xcode to build a new group. But when I try to run the project, Xcode still can't find these code. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When you see a file that is red (or in the wrong place), you can easily correct the location of these files by using the file inspector (which appears along the right side panel of your Xcode window).

It looks like this:

[image: Use File Inspector to fix path]

Clicking on the Folder icon next to the name will bring up an open panel from which you can choose the correct location of the file.

Comment: The trouble is that I have remove the reference of these red files. When I drag files into xcode again, xcode still tell me files are missed.

Comment: so are the files still red or?

Comment: I find that it needs some time for xcode to recognize  the missed files I have dragged in . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

There is an easier way to re-organize files through the Xcode project. You can use `Synx`, it automatically fixes file paths, through the Xcode project groups.

You can check Github page for Synx

[Synx](https://github.com/venmo/synx)

After intalling Synx just run the command below

`synx path/to/my/project.xcodeproj`

Comment: Super +1. This worked perfectly for my inherited project with horrible flat file organization.

Comment: Why did I only find this now? Love it!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

3 things

1
removed the reference to the red files
then dragged them back into the project
relinked all my .m and .h files just incase

2
then removed the .app reference and dragged it back in to the project.

3
removed any duplicates or red files in the build phases

Fixed
Thanks everyone for your suggestions and help

Answer (score 1):

1. Drag the new files from the finder to the Xcode project file structure.
2. Remove the old files.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view i would definitely avoid the virtual folders in the Xcode.The disadventage of this approach is whe nthe project gets bigger and bigger you can not find corresponding files in your filesystem easy.Even you click on "Show in finder" you need to look for the file among tens of files.

My approach is creating the folder in the finder and then dragging it to project.when i need to create a new file in this subfolder is will be added there anyhow.

Comment: ..... I find the more you create real folders, the harder the project becomes to manage... far and wide. Xcode does not play well with real folders vs groups

Comment: I use this approach for ages and never had problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of class and find a good solution for solve this problem :)

1- Select a file that you want to change the location (Red)

2- Select "show the file inspector" from right side in Xcode

3- Select wrong path or unexpected path and copy like this screenshot

[image]

4- Close your project

5- Go to your root project and right click on "project *.xcodeproj" and select "Show package contents"

6- Right click on "project.pbxproj" and open with TextEdit

7- In the file select "Find and replace" or click on " Option+Command+F " and find location that you copied and replace with "" empty

8- Save and open the Xcode :)