# Xcode 5 Framework/Library Search Path Absolute Address

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcode5, search-path

I updated my Xcode to 5.0. I added some library/framework search paths and the path it's displaying is the absolute path. For example, if my folder is in my desktop it would display /Users/username/Desktop/"foldername"/"subfolder"/"subfolder"/"framework".
Because of this, whenever I check out a working copy in another mac, I have to remove references to certain libraries/frameworks and add them back in. Isn't there a way to fix it where I don't have to remove-add reference again?

Comment: Sure. Move or copy your framework into your source folder before adding it to your project, instead of adding it to your project directly from the folder living on your desktop.

Comment: so you're saying i should use add files instead of dragging the folder to the projecT? wouldn't removing reference and using add files do the trick?

Comment: yep... that will work also (in terms of fixing your problem right now).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here's what i did: 
$(SRCROOT)/"subfolder"/"subfolder"/"framework" 
This is what we're using before in previous Xcode versions. The reason why it wasn't working with Xcode5 is because; for some reason, whenever you add another framework to your project, it automatically adds a "\" so you need to remove those to make it work. I don't know why it does that.

Comment: I actually put in $(SRCROOT) only without the subfolders or framework and it solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: whenever i add new libraries (.a file) into my project, xcode5 automatically adds letter "\" to all paths in Library Search Path, so I can't build anymore before fixing it manually. And unfortunately the project has 9 targets!

Comment: is there any way to make this being the default behavior? thanks

Comment: hi Frade. I'm sorry i don't know if there's a way to make it the default behavior.

Comment: Hello cessmestreet can you explain why you put quotes for the subfolder names ? It works but I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work without quotes. Example : My_App only works by "My App" I also tried My\ App.

Comment: @3366784 I'm no expert but based from observation I think that's because the "" indicates that whatever is inside it is the whole name of the subfolder including the space.

Answer (score 21):

I was able to solve the same problem with the latest Xcode (v5.1), add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)                     recursive
```

Comment: This fixed it for me but I had to use non-recursive and point it directly to the correct folder (but using project_dir so it works on multiple systems)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to add in a folder full of files, when you drag it into your project, is to make certain the "Copy Items Into Destination Folder" checkbox is checked to on.

[image: use that handy checkbox]

Then you'll avoid the trouble you've just found yourself in.

Comment: but i already did that. the libraries folders are already in my project. thanks for the reply. :)

Comment: If they're already in your source code folder, then you need to reset their locations so that your project thinks they are not on your desktop.  [This question has the answer you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020582/how-can-i-change-the-location-of-files-in-xcode-project/19020652#19020652).

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19928354/1698467):

Well I faced the same issue and $(SRCROOT) didn't help. Here's the fix that worked for me. Go to framework search paths. Delete whatever is there and add ./ and make it recursive.

Answer (score 0):

Copied and pasted `~/Library/SDKs/ArcGIS/iOS/ArcGIS.framework` directly into `/Developer/Frameworks`.

App still isn't compiling, but I think this solved my issue here.

Answer (score 0):

1- Add $(SRCROOT) in Framework Search Paths and make it recursive.

2- If the previous step is not worked, go to Copy Bundle Resources and delete ArcGIS.bundle and then add it again.

Answer (score 0):

Happens when you have the same file name already.