# Xcode warning with non-standard Framework ld: warning: directory not found for option -F

Tags: xcode, frameworks, linker, ld

Cleaning up warnings, I could see the following:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/myPath/etc/myframework'
```

This was happening with non-standard iOS frameworks. How to eliminate the warning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Checking the man page of the linker `ld` shows the following detail for the `-Fdir` option:

> Add dir to the list of directories in which to search for frameworks. 
>   Directories specified with -F are searched in the
>                    order they appear on the command line and before the default search path. In Xcode4 and later, there can be a space
>                    between the -F and directory.

Sure enough, checking the `project.pbxproj` showed the missing folder:

```
FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = (
                    "\"$(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks\"",
                    "\"$(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks\"",
                    "\"myPath/etc/myframework\"",
                );
```

So, I thought the whole deal with frameworks was that they avoided all this hassle. Well, that's true for *standard* frameworks, i.e. the SDK ones. For anything else, more tweakery is required. From [Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html):

> Locating Frameworks in Non-Standard Directories
>
> If your project links to frameworks that are not included in any of
>   the standard locations, you must explicitly specify the location of
>   that framework before Xcode can locate its header files. To specify
>   the location of such a framework, add the directory containing the
>   framework to the “Framework Search Paths” option of your Xcode
>   project. Xcode passes this list of directories to the compiler and
>   linker, which both use the list to search for the framework resources.
>
> Note: The standard locations for frameworks are the
>   /System/Library/Frameworks directory and the /Library/Frameworks
>   directory on the local system.

Turns out in Xcode's Build Settings, there is a specific entry for Framework Search Paths.

Adding the generic catch-all entry of `$(SRCROOT)` as per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130744/xcode-5-framework-library-search-path-absolute-address) did the business and eliminated the warnings. Oh, and *don't forget to set the drop down to "Recursive"*.