# iOS Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: ios

When I'm try to compile my project I get error. I added all required frameworks - AVFoundation,opencv and many other , but it don't help me.Here is few lines from this error:

```
     Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MACaptureSession.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDeviceInput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MACaptureSession.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MACaptureSession.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureStillImageOutput", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MACaptureSession.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MACaptureSession.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CABasicAnimation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAImagePickerFinalViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATransition", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAImagePickerControllerAdjustViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in MAImagePickerController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPVolumeView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MAImagePickerController.o
  "_kCATransition", referenced from:
      -[MAImagePickerControllerAdjustViewController confirmedImage] in MAImagePickerControllerAdjustViewController.o
```

Comment: Here is frameworks from project:
MediaPlayer,
AudioToolbox,
CoreImage,
QuartzCore,
ImageIO,
CoreMedia,
AVFoundation,
opencv2,
Foundation,
CoreGraphics,
UIKit

Comment: Try this, clean -> close xcode -> build..

Comment: @Mani situation don't changed

Comment: Did you try this `Go to framework search paths. Remove everything from there`? Also try this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130744/xcode-5-framework-library-search-path-absolute-address.

Comment: Did you try to compile with an iPod or iPhone? It seems that you compile your application with a library which is not supported simulator in the simulator. For example: AVFoundation. Try NSLog(@"%@", [AVCaptureDevice devices]); in simulator, you will see no Device

Answer (score 2):

Just add 
`CoreMedia.framework` and with `AVFoundation.framework` to your project.

Got to.

Project -> target -> Build phases -> Link binary with library -> "+" -> select your frameworks

Comment: CoreMedia.framework and AVFoundation.framework are already in project

Comment: Ok... then add which you did not added  CoreMedia.framework","AudioToolbox.framework","CoreGraphics.framework","CoreVideo.framework","AVFoundation.framework","libiconv.dylib"

Comment: @STBY - Ok then have added "-ObjC" to other linker flags ?

Answer (score 1):

check wheter the 
MACaptureSession
MAImagePickerFinalViewController
MAImagePickerControllerAdjustViewController
MAImagePickerController.m
have been added in target and check in respective m files,wheter implementation name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Mani add required frameworks. If you have already added these frameworks and still getting error, set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `NO` under project 's Build Settings.

Comment: After this set number of errors has increased by several times