# Xcode project/app name with spaces issue - framework not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

Is it possible that Xcode 6.1 doesn't finds my previously imported frameworks because of my 3 word app name? I'm using Parse and never ever had any problems with it. But actually when I open my project in Xcode I got an error that the framework doesn't found, which is absurd because it worked well earlier and I don't removed it. However if I delete the frameworks and add them again everything is fine. Am I doing something wrong or is it an Xcode bug?

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/donip/Documents/Fl Travel Guide/Fl'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FTravel'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FGuide'
ld: framework not found ParseFacebookUtils
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Adding backslashes `-F/Users/donip/Documents/Fl\ Travel\ Guide/Fl`

Comment: @YuchenZhong nope. I should rename the folder or something like that?

Comment: i mean add '\' before space. So it looks like this `Fl\ Travel\ Guide/Fl`

Comment: @YuchenZhong I understand, but where should I add them? Do I need to create a new project or just edit the folder name?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this question: Do you mean you get this problem after you upgrade to Xcode 6.1? And it is all fine before? And if you remove and reimport the framework, everything works just fine?

Comment: @YuchenZhong No. I created the project in 6.1, everything worked well until I closed Xcode. After I opened it again got the error, then deleted & added the frameworks again and now it works.

Comment: Can you provide your "Framework search path" and actual framework path in Finder?

Comment: @mr.lefthand please accept any answer that suits best.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Simply enclose your framework path in double quotes(""). For example:

"$(SRCROOT)/my framework/path"

[image]

Answer (score 8):

"directory not found for option '-F/..."

Here '-F/..' shows it's a Framework Error. There could be 2 reasons for this.

1. Missing escape "\" character.

   It seems search paths are broken up on several lines in the Framework Search Path or Library Search Paths. Or having spaces in path. Add the escape "\" character to fix it.
2. Click on your project (targets)->
   Click on Build Settings->
   Under Frameworks Search Paths, delete the paths.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure this is Xcode bug. Since a lot of other developers have problems with 
frameworks paths, such as [Absolute path issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130744/xcode-5-framework-library-search-path-absolute-address)
I'm sure You will find other issues too in SO.

I have encountered this issues myself  too.
Best solution for me just commit working project files, and then 
reset/revert new/wrong changes which done by Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I had to delete (using Terminal):

```
/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME
```

Using:

```
rm -r PROJECT_NAME-xxxxxxxx
```

If you have multiple projects with the same name in the `/DerivedData` folder, first try deleting all but the most recent one. If that does not work, try deleting all projects including the most recent.

Answer (score 1):

Just update your library location to such a path which doesn't have any spaces inbetween. For example, instead of :

```
'-F/Users/donip/Documents/Fl Travel Guide/Fl'
```

use

```
'-F/Users/donip/Documents/FlTravelGuide/Fl'
```

Just change the folder name, available in that path, then make the same change in project settings in `Library Search Paths` and `Header Search Paths`, wherever its been referred.

Hope this will resolve your query.