# iOS app with FB SDK reporting FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h file not found

Tags: ios, facebook, fbsdk

I am trying to use the FB SDK with an iOS app, and have added the .framework files to my Frameworks group. I also have added `/Users/$(USER)/Documents/FacebookSDK` to my search path.

I am getting an error when building: `FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h file not found`

This is accurate, because `/Users/$(USER)/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h` does not exist.

Instead, the file is at: `/Users/$(USER)/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/Headers/FBSDKCoreKit.h`

What am I supposed to do about this? (Or what am I doing wrong?)

I followed the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

Comment: Make sure you did this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32957413/5872894

Answer (score 0):

Remove all facebook framework then after Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths then add facebook framework

```
 $(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.

**OR**

You have duplicate symbol method which means there are duplicate file in project

In your Target's Build Phase, under "Compile Sources" check if there are duplicate file and delete one if you have duplication.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes the libraries does not get grabbed by Xcode, Try cleaning the project

Try with  $(inherited) and non-recursive in library search paths for project target in Build settings.