# Facebook Framework is already added in project but still shows errors like "No such module FBSDKCoreKit"

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

I am integrating FB SDK in my swift project and i follow [this link](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/facebook-sdk-ios-login-example-with-swift/) and also [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/advanced) i followed. I also `import FBSDKCoreKit` in
`appDelegate.swift` file but i am always getting the error like

> "No Such Module FBSDKCoreKit"

I found some solution and even i tried most of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32078947/no-such-module-fbsdkcorekit-xcode-7-4) also i tried [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29466683/could-not-build-module-fbsdkcorekit-for-facebooksdk-4) and also followed [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift), even i added bridging-header file to project and import FBSDK to that file but still i am getting errors every time and i am stuck here from last 3 days.

If you have any solutions except this given link please help me as i am new to Swift

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32096787/no-such-module-fbsdkcorekit-error

Comment: No Duplication and also added framework search path not even ticked to Copy if needed

Comment: @AshishThakkar your error gone or still have ?

Answer (score 0):

open your project [image]

Remove FBSDKCoreKit module into linked frameworks and libraries and add again it and clean and build your app your error will be gone.

happy coding.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me buddy.!

Comment: @AshishThakkar did you remove the library from link framework and add again in it ?

Comment: yes exactly i did whatever you said

Comment: @AshishThakkar possible then send your project i check it and i solve your porblem

Comment: how can i send you project

Comment: @AshishThakkar got my id ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126224/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-ashish-thakkar).

Comment: I got solution for this issue

Comment: @AshishThakkar what is solution for this ?

Comment: Downloaded old version of sdk and implement in project and issue resolved.

Comment: but in my case i use leatest version and its 4.0 and i resolve this problem with this step that i give you . and its good you solve your problem yourself. @AshishThakkar

Comment: welcome and thank you for share your knowledge