# No such module `FBSDKCoreKit`

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdk

I'm using FBSDK via cocoapods for my current project.
I'm getting error

> 'FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h' file not found

while using bridging header.
 or getting error

> No such module `FBSDKCoreKit`
>   while not importing FBSDK in bridging header.

I've already visited following links but not getting help.
[No such module FBSDKCoreKit error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32096787/4844767)
[No such module 'FBSDKCoreKit' XCODE 7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32078947/4844767)
[Facebook Framework is already added in project but still shows errors like "No such module FBSDKCoreKit"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40130238/4844767)

Please help me to solve this issue

**Note:** Using code 7.3 with Swift 2.2 / 2.3

Comment: Are you getting any other output in the warnings/errors? are you definately opening the workspace and not the project? have you ensured that the FBCoreKit framework is linked?. Please provide as much information as you can, you will get better solutions rather than people presuming things

Comment: Yes I'm opening workspace instead of project file. and error is already mentioned in question.

Comment: check the bolts framework also

Comment: already added bolts

Answer (score 1):

Can you maybe try checking your header search paths and making sure it only has $(inherited) and nothing else? You can find it at your Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths and making sure it only has $(inherited) recursive.