# Getting exit code1 error while integrating the ccavenue payment gateway

Tags: ios, objective-c, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I'm getting the following error while integrating the **ccavenue** payment gateway.

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

[check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4irY.png)

Comment: try this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/18916600/4831524

Comment: thanks for the reply i am not having any red color files in build phases also i cleaned my project many times and checked but it not works for me ..

Comment: You should check two classes with same name added in your Xcode project or Isn't you import .m file??

Comment: the problem is i just running the ccavenue payment gateway sample .In that i don't no how to add library search path and header search path .In that some how i added the library search path but i didn't add the header search so that only the problem coming i think so.can u pls explain me how to add the following both paths in the project .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19131578/4831524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]HI just follow this simple steps:

1.create a new folder in ur source folder name as: **openssl**

2.in side **openssl** create a another folder name as **lib**

3.add all **.h** files of **ccavenue** files to ur open ssl

4.add all the **.a lib** files in **lib** folder

4.1. create new group in ur project in Xcode and name as **openssl**
copy all the files in the  **openssl** what u created in the previous.

4.2. create another new group in **openssl** name as **lib** copy all the lib files in to it.

5.in your project under the target in build settings  type linker:
u can find **OtherLinkerFlags** 
add(reference if its required)

```
-ObjC
-framework
-lc++
$(inherited)
```

6.next search for **search paths**: (in search)

in lib search paths add

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
$(inherited)
$(PROJECT_DIR)/openssl/lib
```

finish lets clean the project (win + shift+k)

run it.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, still i am getting the same error i followed all ur steps mentioned above,also i added the images for ur reference.

Comment: ok maybe u given wrong path of ur lib files. can u take screenshot of ur projects path what u given and where u crated the files

Comment: i added the image pls check it

Comment: what is the mistake?

Comment: that is my resources folder inside I have my project  name and workspace here u need to add openssl folder

Comment: i am getting the following error after following your steps. 1) Unknown type name 'XSym' .                                                                                                     2) Expected identifier or '('                                                                              3) '@end' must appear in an Objective-C context                                                    can u pls suggest me how to rectify that error