# xcode 5.0.2 .app file is now Red getting Apple Match-O Linker error

Tags: xcode, ipad, product, .app

I recently moved a ipad project I was working on to a new folder and thought I changed everything so it would run.
Apparently not.

I searched all over the forum but none of the answers seemed to be the problem.

When I clean the app it is successful but fails to run.

My .app file in Products folder is now red.

this is the error I am getting and can't figure out what has changed.

the only other new thing is that i renewed my DEV account with apple.
But none of my other xcode projects are having this problem.

**** I noticed that my project name and the Build name seem to be different.

i would post the image here but seems i'm not allowed.

error code:

```
Ld /Users/mo-ry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prop_Tablet-czmhxyzuhrifndgzesduqempenjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Prop\ Tablet.app/Prop\ Tablet normal i386
    cd "/Developer/Xcode 5.2 Projects/1 SUBMIT to App Store/Prop Tablet Blue_Green"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk -L/Users/mo-ry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prop_Tablet-czmhxyzuhrifndgzesduqempenjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/mo-ry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prop_Tablet-czmhxyzuhrifndgzesduqempenjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/mo-ry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prop_Tablet-czmhxyzuhrifndgzesduqempenjo/Build/Intermediates/Prop\ Tablet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Prop\ Tablet.build/Objects-normal/i386/Prop\ Tablet.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mo-ry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prop_Tablet-czmhxyzuhrifndgzesduqempenjo/Build/Intermediates/Prop\ Tablet.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Prop\ Tablet.build/Objects-normal/i386/Prop\ Tablet_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mo-ry/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Prop_Tablet-czmhxyzuhrifndgzesduqempenjo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Prop\ Tablet.app/Prop\ Tablet

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

An Xcode project simply holds references to file paths and does not represent the actual underlying directory structure of your project directory. Understand this and you will be able to solve a great many problems that people have with Xcode.

Before you moved your iPad project, its references to the files within the project were correct - after moving it, the references are no longer correct. This is a complaint so many devs have with Xcode and it causes so many problems.

What you will need to do is go through each file in your project in Xcode navigation pane and check that it's file reference location matches where it is physically on disk.

I suspect that your project held relative file path references, and when you moved it they're not in the same relative location.

This is the area of Xcode where you can change the file path references:
[image: Xcode File Identity and Type Pane] (referenced from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19020652/76559)

In answer to your specific error message - the linker is telling you that it can't find the symbol for the main function. What probably happened is that during the move the mian.m file was somehow removed from the target for your app (did you create a new target in trying to solve the issue and forget to add the `main.m` file to it?

Comment: ya know I have tried SO many things to try and fix this I may have created a new target but I dont thinks so. I did try to relink the .app file path in the area you circled. but it is grey out. So i cant change the path. NOt sure why.