# Change Xcode c++ application external file location

Tags: c++, xcode, directory

I am first time using Xcode and C++
I wrote a program which has to load some images. I changed the working directory in the Xcode so the files are located correctly.
But after I build the project and compile it as an application, the external file directory is changed to "usr/[myuser]" (i used char * dir = getcwd(NULL, 0); to get the path)

Does any has an idea how to change the file directory?
Or how can I include these files in the project?

Comment: This question has already [been asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020582/how-can-i-change-the-location-of-files-in-xcode-project).

Comment: That question is asking about c++ files, not external files

Comment: okay, I've retracted my close vote. You need to provide some more detail to make this a truly answerable question, such as: Where are your image files located?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the bar above scheme 
Click edit scheme 
Checkmark Custom working directory 
Choose your directory of choice

Files in this directory are now accessible by the project