# Unable to get xcode project to index appropriate directories

Tags: swift, xcode

So I had to delete my project and then reclone it from my repository, but when I clone down the project and I open it, other files from some time ago show in there, how is this possible?

Example this is the cloned directory:
[image]

But when I open the project, it shows this project structure:
[image]

Also it produces the following error when attempting to build the project:

```
Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/Development/Projects/MapGlider/Application/Utilities/Extensions.swift'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it?
```

All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the project as you see it in Xcode is a combination of file system + information about your project in `YourProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` file. So you have a mismatch between file system and that file, which is typically a result of inaccurate checkin (for example some changes were done directly in file system, and the project was not updated), or a bad merge (developer A did everything right, developer B, or even the same developer on a different branch, overrode those changes incorrectly).

So what you need to do is to fix those errors one by one.

Note: the steps below assume the project is in your control. If you are using some script or tool to *generate* the project, you will have to address those issues via that tool or script instead.

**First, fix the project structure:**

1. Make sure Inspectors on the right side in Xcode are open. Choose **File inspector** tab
2. Focus on a folder inside Xcode, and check Name, Location and Full Path of the folder. Especially notice the Full Path, if it's incorrect, change it to a correct one. [Here's the example how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19020652/5318223). Repeat for all folders and files you want to have in the project
3. Delete all folders and files you don't want to have in the project from Xcode. For example you can delete `Extensions` which appears as a file in your project, while it's actually a folder. Typically while deleting you should be able to delete them from file system as well if it exists, but if not, you can double check in file system and delete files / folders from there as well.
4. Add folders and files missing from the project if needed. Follow [Add existing files and folders to a project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/managing-files-and-folders-in-your-xcode-project) section in the linked page.

Once you cleaned up the project, you need to review / fix all your project targets:

**To fix the Project targets**

Try to build each target. If it succeeds, most likely everything is resolved (although watch out for runtime errors for resource files - so you may need to test your app to ensure nothing is missing too).

If building a target fails, you will need to see why. For example

- if file is missing from the target, but you already added it to the Xcode project, you can add it to the target (see [this page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-a-new-target-in-your-project)).
- if file is missing from the target and is not visible in Xcode, go back to step 4 of the previous procedure and add those files to Xcode project, and then add them to the target
- if a file is nowhere to find and is not needed, you can delete it from target. If it was needed, then... well, you have a problem and need to locate your missing code in your source repo or rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks for this! I will follow all the steps to attempt to delete this, is there anyway to completely remove the data and sync between the projects and then clone it down and completely treat it as a new project?

Comment: Depends on the condition of the project in your remote source form which you clone. As you said you already cloned it, and it's already broken after clone, so it seems the project is broken in the remote repo, and there's no way around it.

Comment: When I commit a xcode project in Github, do you know what project files I should commit under .xcodeproj? I want to avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: Yes, it's a known pain point with Xcode projects, not yet addressed by Apple. Typically you should commit the whole `xcodeproj` folder, but not the `xcworkspace` folder. To avoid this pain in the future... there are no good ways, other than making sure you "properly" do all the changes through Xcode and merge. There are some tools, which allow to define project declaratively, and then build it locally on each machine (so this semi-binary pbxproj file is never checked in), but it's not easy. See this for example: https://www.splinter.com.au/2021/05/17/xcode-project-generator/

Comment: I really appreciate the help, this is going to help so much - These are the files and folders that I have inside `.xcodeproj`, `project.pbxproj, project.xcworkspace & xcuserdata/` - Should we not commit the `xcuserdata/` folder?

Comment: It depends on project, work habits, company rules, etc, but the general rule is that the contents of `. xcodeproj` are "project definition", and should be committed with all its content to the repo. But you don't need `.xcworkspace` and its contents in the source repo, since it contains "current state" of the Xcode for this project, and hence doesn't belong to the repo. Check this gitignore prototype, it explains various options: https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/xcode,swift,macos